# How to get alsa dummy soundcard on debian in Docker

Tags: audio, debian, docker, alsa

I am trying to configure a dummy sound card in a Debian docker container.
Unfortunately the documentation I find on the internet is incomplete and old.
I was mainly looking at [this post on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux4noobs/comments/2m77g1/help_a_noob_create_a_dummy_sound_card_driver/) and [this post on superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/344760/how-to-create-a-dummy-sound-card-device-in-linux-server).
For starters, installing `alsa-base`:
  - [jessie/alsa-base](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/alsa-base) - says it's dummy empty package and functionality ships with kmod
  - [debian/sound](https://packages.debian.org/stable/sound/) - long list of alsa-related packages, but no `alsa-base`, again - most alsa packages depend on `kmod`.
So I decided I may start with something like so:

```
FROM debian:stretch-slim
USER root
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y kmod
RUN touch /etc/modprobe.d/myalias.conf
RUN echo "alias char-major-116 snd" >> /etc/modprobe.d/myalias.conf
RUN echo "alias snd-card-0 snd-dummy" >> /etc/modprobe.d/myalias.conf
RUN modprobe snd-dummy
```

But at the point of doing modprobe I am getting:

```
modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:586 kmod_search_moddep() could not open moddep file '/lib/modules/4.9.125-linuxkit/modules.dep.bin'
modprobe: FATAL: Module snd-dummy not found in directory /lib/modules/4.9.125-linuxkit
```

Any advice on what am I missing? Thanks :)

Comment: You may find some answers in [post1](https://superuser.com/questions/1223118/emulating-microphone-input-to-chrome-inside-docker-container) or [post2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28985714/run-apps-using-audio-in-a-docker-container).

Comment: Have you tried any of the methods in the links?

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar issue recently and solution for me was running docker container in privileged mode with `--privileged=true` parameter. Not sure if it is also a solution for this one, but you may give it a try.